# my php code inside of jquery code doesn't get executed

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script>
$('#tes').click(function(){    
<?php $output = ''; 
  foreach( $votes as $array) 
    if($array->color === $colors->color)       
   $output = $output . $array->votes . '<br>';?>  
     $('#Result').html(<?php $output ?>);
   });
</script>
```

how should I rewrite it to make it work?

Comment: Using PHP inside some JavaScript...and I thought mixing up PHP and HTML is the top of the things...

Comment: Well... That's a minus for coding style. You can't, just can't mix JavaScript and PHP, especially like that.

Read about clean code, loose coupling, and how web works on the client and server sides.

Comment: PHP executes on the server, Javascript on the client, and never twain shall they meet except via AJAX calls.

Comment: Guys, this is NOT a duplicate. This guy doesn't have an `echo` in front of `$output`. While the code is ugly, and warrants criticism, it's not at all the same issue as the other SO post marked.

Comment: @jszobody OK, admittedly that *may* be the actual issue. But it seems just as likely to me that the dupe is appropriate. We don't know anything about what this code is *supposed* to do, so can't say for sure. Either way it's a lazy question.

Comment: @deceze So now we're marking dups just because we "can't say for sure"?? Lazy != duplicate.

Comment: @jszobody Want to reopen it to close as "demonstrate some basic understanding"? :)

Comment: @deceze Ha, that might work. =)

Answer (score 0):

Messy code issues aside, this:

```
<?php $output ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php echo $output ?>
```

Also note that your JavaScript `html()` function will need a string, which means quotes around the HTML. Something like:

```
$('#Result').html("<?php $output ?>")
```

But then if your PHP `$output` has quotes in it, that'll break. So then you'll need to look at [`addslashes()`](https://www.php.net/addslashes).

While this should fix your current issues, the commenters are right that this is a horribly messy/ugly way to write code, you need to refactor this significantly.

**Suggestion:** One way to make this a bit cleaner would be like this:

```
// At the top of your page
<?php
$output = '';
foreach( $votes as $array) {
    if($array->color === $colors->color) {
        $output .= $array->votes . '<br>';
    }
}
?>

// Down in your HTML code somewhere
<div id="output" style="display:none"><?php echo $output ?></div>

// Now for the much simpler javascript
<script>
    $('#tes').click(function(){
        $("#output").show();
    });
</script>
```

This way you have *minimal* mixing of PHP with HTML/JS, you don't have to worry about escaping quotes, the PHP `$output` is already on your page (hidden) ahead of time, and JavaScript just has to show it.

Comment: Do not encourage that type of programming

Comment: @Fratyr It's still answering his specific question. which I thought was a GOOD thing to do here on SO!

Comment: thank you for the comments i thought that one liner of php would not require whole ajax call besides how would php know which color was picked? little of noob style was simple hacking

Comment: @user3022152 Did this answer solve your problem?

Comment: any suggestions regarding actual code how to make it more amenable

Comment: Separate out your PHP and HTML/JS code as much as possible. Build your `$output` at the top of the page first, in pure PHP. Then later perhaps do `<div id="output" style="display: none"><?php echo $output ?></div>`. Finally your javascript can then simply do `$("#output").show()`. Make sense? You have minimal php code mixed in with the HTML/JS.

Comment: @user3022152 I updated my answer with a suggestion on how to refactor. I'm making a few assumptions about your page, you'd have to tweak it to work in your situation.